# Nginx: Bad Gateway 502 error

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, php-fpm

I am running Nginx with PHP5-FPM on Amazon EC2 on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. I get a bad gateway error whenever I got to my site. I know that it is a configuration issue but I am not sure what is badly configured.

My error log:

```
2012/11/17 05:29:19 [error] 9519#0: *4 open() "/var/www/growyourbutt.com/robots.txt" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 131.253.41.146, server: growyourbut$
2012/11/17 05:29:19 [error] 9519#0: *5 open() "/var/www/growyourbutt.com/wp-content/themes/wp-bold107/images/facebook.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), clien$
2012/11/17 05:30:36 [error] 9519#0: *6 "/var/www/growyourbutt.com/tag/brazilian-butt-lift-surgery-cost/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: $
2012/11/17 05:31:56 [error] 9519#0: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 67.85.186.145, server: growyourbutt.com, reques$
2012/11/17 05:31:56 [error] 9519#0: *10 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 188.138.0.168, server: growyourbutt.com, reque$
2012/11/17 05:31:57 [error] 9519#0: *12 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 188.138.0.168, server: growyourbutt.com, reque$
2012/11/17 05:32:00 [error] 9519#0: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 67.85.186.145, server: growyourbutt.com, reques$
2012/11/17 05:33:37 [error] 9519#0: *15 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 67.85.186.145, server: growyourbutt.com, reque$
2012/11/17 05:33:44 [error] 9519#0: *18 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 67.85.186.145, server: growyourbutt.com, reque$
2012/11/17 05:33:44 [error] 9519#0: *18 open() "/var/www/growyourbutt.com/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 67.85.186.145, server: growyourbu$
2012/11/17 05:35:29 [error] 9519#0: *20 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 220.181.108.160, server: growyourbutt.com, req$
2012/11/17 05:35:45 [error] 9519#0: *22 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 123.125.71.111, server: growyourbutt.com, requ$
```

My `nginx.conf`:

```
ser www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;

 ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        port_in_redirect off;

 server_tokens off;

        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        port_in_redirect off;
        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

 gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascr$

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##

        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

If anyone can help me figure this out, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Your problem doesn't related to nginx at all. It's obvious from error log, that nginx cannot connect to php-fpm, so you should look at php-fpm.

Answer (score 1):

php-fpm isn't running. Restart the service.

Answer (score -1):

**502 bad gateway** means that your PHP5-FPM is dying and NGINX can't listen your php5-fpm.

Check the error.log of your php5-fpm application on /var/log, solve the error, and then restart your php5-fpm